# Can't use my Google profile pic

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, login, profile-picture

Recently I signed up for the [elementary SE](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/) the same way I've signed for all the sites in the network, via my Google credentials.

Now, if I navigate to my profile and then to the `Edit Profile & Settings` tab *from within the elementary SE* I see that if I click on `Change picture`, I can select my Google pic as an option.

I've done this and saved clicking the `Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities` button, which results in the message:

> Your profile has been saved successfully.

This nonetheless seems to have no effect whatsoever and my old profile pic is still used across all my communities.

I've checked accessing my profile in other communities  where I also log in using my Google credentials) and in neither of them do I have the choice to select my Google pic; even here in Meta. I just see the options `Uploaded picture` and `Identicon`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try removing cache or use different browser. See if that helps

Comment: How long ago was this? It was only a few minutes it *could* be caching, but I would expect the update to happen fairly promptly.

Comment: Nope, tried two days ago. Also how do you explain that the option to select my Google pic appears only in one of my communities?

Comment: Normally, selecting a Google avatar to use on SE is available during signup... And we may have missed something when it comes to saving profiles network-wide. I'll have to look to see how it works to be sure. Retagging as "bug" in the meantime, because it probably is.

Comment: @AnnaLear any updates on this issue? Is there an open bug I could track?

Comment: @Gabriel This post *is* the bug report you can track. :) I'll be looking at this today.

Comment: Thank you @AnnaLear! (I thought perhaps you had a Github repo or something)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heh. Turns out, we forgot to handle the "Google avatar" case on profile edits entirely. I pushed a fix that will be live as of rev 2015.7.21.3599 here on meta and 2015.7.21.2743 elsewhere.

This unfortunately won't fix your ability to see Google as an option on other sites until after you save it to all profiles once from elementaryOS because of a limitation in how we populate those.

Options like Google and Facebook are only available during signup where we can actually get them during the authentication process. Avatar providers not available at that point become essentially off-limits forever even if you add credentials from those providers later. On subsequent profile edits, we populate that choice list with the providers that are always available (upload your own, Gravatar, and Identicon) + ones we find in your user history from previous avatar changes.

That last part is why once you save your changes to all communities, Google should appear as an avatar option on the sites you currently have.

I'll add looking into checking for avatar options when someone adds a login credential to my list, but it's realistically not likely to happen any time soon.